# Laptop takes for ever to change to "sleep" mode and when wakes up doesn't recognize the wireless keyboard and mouse

Tags: windows-7, sleep, dell-latitude, wake-up

I used to have a problem when I try to make my laptop go to "sleep" mode.
It took few min to complete the task.

Another issue was that when I connected the laptop to the docking station and wake up the laptop (from "sleep" mode) then the wireless keyboard and mouse were not detected. Only reboot fixed that.

I ran a Microsoft "fix it" utility and it found a service that didn't run although it used to run in the past. Once I started the service everything worked great.

I forgot the name of the service but it's related to the memory management of the OS.

Now when I run the "fix it" it doesn't say anything about the service but I'm 100% sure it's the same problem since I"m seeing the same problem that I had before.

Does anyone know which service it is and maybe other suggestions?

Dotan.